# Transformation of one column to two?

Tags: xml, xslt

I use a template to show what I am looking for. XSLT is new to me.

XML:

```
<info>
    <ID>5</ID> 
    <Name>A</Name> 
</info>
<info>
    <ID>5</ID> 
    <Name>B</Name> 
</info>
<info>
    <ID>5</ID> 
    <Name>C</Name> 
</info>
<info>
    <ID>5</ID> 
    <Name>D</Name> 
</info>
<info>
    <ID>5</ID> 
    <Name>E</Name> 
</info>
<info>
    <ID>5</ID> 
    <Name>F</Name> 
</info>
<info>
    <ID>5</ID> 
    <Name>G</Name> 
</info>
<info>
    <ID>5</ID> 
    <Name>H</Name> 
</info>
<info>
    <ID>5</ID> 
    <Name>I</Name> 
</info>
<info>
    <ID>5</ID> 
    <Name>J</Name> 
</info>
```

The output which I am looking for is:

```
    A           E
    B           F
    C           G
    D           H
```

As per the input xml output are not proper.

Comment: And also there is no defined number of node exist in xml. thanks

Comment: Is the output mode `text` or `html`?

Comment: Yes I am looking for HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you haven't specify the output format, the following XSLT just outputs a simple HTML.

```
<xsl:template match="items"> <!-- original XML should be wrapped in a parent element `items`-->
    <xsl:variable name="rows" select="count(item) div 2"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="item[position() &lt;= $rows]">
      <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="name"/> 
      <xsl:value-of select="../item[$pos + $rows]"/> 
      <br/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

**Update** Since you just explicitly specify that output format is in HTML, this way may be better:

```
<xsl:template match="items">
    <xsl:variable name="rows" select="count(item) div 2"/>
    <ul id="left-column">
        <xsl:for-each select="item[position() &lt;= $rows]">
            <li><xsl:value-of select="name"/></li>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
    <ul id="right-column">
        <xsl:for-each select="item[position() > $rows]">
            <li><xsl:value-of select="name"/></li>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>
```

To make output exactly meet your requirement, we need add CSS style to make left-column float left and right-column float right, and customize list-style, spacing etc.

Comment: Yes I am looking for HTML.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
  <xsl:template match="items">
    <table>
      <xsl:variable name="rowCount" select="ceiling(count(info) div 2)" />
      <xsl:for-each select="info[position() &lt;= $rowCount]">
        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
        <td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="../info[$pos + $rowCount]/Name"/>
          </td>
        </td>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: And what was wrong with it?  Would you like to give us some information about what you specifically want?

Comment: That's not HTML.  As I said above, there are countless ways to produce two columns in HTML.  What kind of HTML would you like?

Comment: <table><tr><td>A</td><td>E</td></tr><tr><td>B</td><td>F</td></tr></table>

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  Added a solution above. It's similar to Hui Zheng's first approach above but adds the table tags.